# TFS project removal

Tags: tfs

We have a project which cannot be removed completely. We use TFS API output all the projects and their size and we find a project which we cannot see it on the web or VS. The project is very big(more than 200G). We try to delete it, but met some problems. I tried to remove it with the command "TFSDeleteproject ..." and got the error message as bellow.

"The team project could not be deleted. Either the delete operation failed, or project creation failed but partially-created project could not be deleted. Review the previous entries in this log for details. The team project has been taken offline and remains in a non-operational state. It is not accessible to Team Explorer. To complete the deletion, address the errors noted in this log, and then attempt deleting the project again."

Is there any other way to remove the project? Any advice is welcomed.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any other detailed logs?

Comment: yes, the operation is timed out, but all the ways of extending timeout on servers by modifying registry failed. We finally destroy the big files and then TFSDeleteproject the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You read [Delete a team project with TFSDeleteProjec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd) guide.
There is even a description on how to Verify Project Deletion.

In addition I think main space occupation can be related on version control files, if this is Your case you can use [TFS Destroy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control) to destroy, or permanently delete, version-controlled files from Team Foundation version control and related changeset history.
If you not like command line, I suggest to use [TFS Source Control Explorer Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-8896)that integrate destroy in source control advanced right click menu.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. Turns about the combination of using TFS source control explorer destroy and TFSDeleteproject works for me. Our problem of deleting the project is that the project is too big and all the ways extending timeout failed, so we have to destroy the files and TFSDeleteproject  to remove other parts.